# How to capture a multiple patterns using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have several text files, containing error values. The values are different in each file and so i'm not able to get the exact line where the value is present.

The example is as follows:

```
v1 = 1111
v2 = A:10 B:2
```

Text:

```
12.10.08,11:12:39,183769  1111,10352,003,12,11:12:39,183 Syntax-->12345
```

(would like to capture v1)

```
01.01.02,06:10:56,243648  00488,00000,018,01,06:10:56,243 A:10 B:2--1212 (would like to capture v2)
```

The regex is as follows:

```
((\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{2}),(\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2},\d*\s*(('+v1+')[,].*|\S*\s('+v2+')).*))
```

Irrespective of the value passed, it should go through text and grab the value. If v1 is present, should provide the complete text and if v2 is present the same. 
But with one regex equation.

Comment: What is the logic here? There is `v1` in the first string, but no `v2` in the second. There is no `1111` in the first string, but there is `A:10 B:2` in the second.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I edited the text. in first example i need to get the 1111 from text. Which is already in the regex.I can also do that for the A:10 B:2 individually. I would like to have one regex which can do both.

Comment: Try a capturing group `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{6}(?: \d{5}(?:,\d+)+:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)? (\d{4}\b|[A-Z]:\d{2} [A-Z]:\d)` https://regex101.com/r/Tn5piG/1

Comment: ⚠️ So `1837` out of `183769` is a valid capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use:

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{6}(?: \d{5}(?:,\d+)+:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)? (\d{4}\b|[A-Z]:\d{2} [A-Z]:\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{6}` Match the format of the starting digits
- `(?: \d{5}(?:,\d+)+:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)?` Optionally match the part starting with 5 digits up until a time like format
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d{4}\b` Match 4 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]:\d{2} [A-Z]:\d` Match `A:10 B:` format
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tn5piG/1)